# finding the number of occurrence of a pattern within a cell in matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell

i have a cell like this:

```
x = {'3D'
    'B4'
    'EF'
    'D8'
    'E7'
    '6C'
    '33'
    '37'}
```

let's assume that the cell is 1000x1. i want to find the number of occurrence of  `pattern = [30;30;64;63]` within this cell  but as the order shown. in the other word it's first check `x{1,1},x{2,1},x{3,1},x{4,1}`
then check `x{2,1},x{3,1},x{4,1},x{5,1}` and like this till the end of the cell and return the number of occurrence of it.

Here is my code but it didn't work!

```
while (size (pattern)< size(x))
    count = 0;
    for i=1:size(x)-length(pattern)+1
        if size(abs(x(i:i+size(pattern)-1)-x))==0
            count = count+1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Your cell `x`looks like hexadecimal value, right ? it will be easier to recognize a pattern if this cell was an array of decimal number.

Comment: yes, but i need to find this pattern among hexadecimal values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code has a couple of issues - foremost I don't believe you are doing any comparison operations, which would be necessary to identify the occurrence of the pattern within the search data (*x*). Also, there is a variable type mismatch between *x* and *pattern* - one is a cell array of strings, and the other is a decimal array.

One way to approach this problem would be to restructure *x* and *pattern* as strings, and then use ***strfind*** to find occurrences of *pattern*. This method will only work if there is no missing data in either of the variables.

```
x = {'3D';'B4';'EF';'D8';'E7';'6C';'33';'37';'xE';'FD';'8y'};
pattern = {'EF','D8'};

collated_x=[x{:}];
collated_pattern = [pattern{:}];
found_locations = strfind(collated_x, collated_pattern);

% Remove 'offset' matches that start at even locations
found_locations = found_locations(mod(found_locations,2)==1);

count = length(found_locations)
```

Comment: so if i want to find a pattern with 4 string i should write like found_locations = found_locations(mod(found_locations,4)==1);?

Comment: Yes, thats right. You could rewrite my code in the following form to make it more flexible: `found_locations = found_locations(mod(found_locations,length(pattern))==1);`

Answer (score 0):

Use string find function.
This is fast and simple solution:

```
clear
str_pattern=['B4','EF'];  %same as str_pattern=['B4EF'];
x = {'3D'
    'B4'
    'EF'
    'D8'
    'EB'
    '4E'
    'F3'
    'B4'
    'EF'
    '37'} ;
str_x=horzcat(x{:});
inds0=strfind(str_x,str_pattern); %including in-middle
inds1=inds0(bitand(inds0,1)==1); %exclude all in-middle results

disp(str_x);
disp(str_pattern);
disp(inds0);
disp(inds1);
```